# Xcodebuild command fails to start simulator

Tags: ios, xcode6, xcodebuild

I am trying to run Xcodebuild test command from terminal (not in any CI) and the command fails with message `xcodebuild:  iPhoneSimulator: Timed out waiting 120 seconds for simulator to boot, current state is 1.`

The command I use is below

`xcodebuild -workspace ProjectName.xcworkspace -scheme ProjectName -sdk iphonesimulator8.4 -derivedDataPath SomeFolder test`

I am able to run the test from Xcode and getting the results, however it doesn't work if I run the command. I did change the time out settings which didn't help me. Any pointers to the issue?

Comment: If you leave off the `-derivedDataPath` flag does it work?

Comment: It didn't work either

Comment: Did you find solution for this? I have xcode7 beta 5 now and have the same issue

Comment: Nope couldn't find it out.